# Dual, double, multiple, parallel language interface display options for digital devices and software

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, multiple-languages, language-comparison, software

I'm looking for ways to display two languages (English and Polish) together on a user interface (UI) when using cell phones, laptops, desktop pcs, tablets (devices) and operating system GUI's, programs, internet browsers (software).
This is for private personal language learning when using these devices and software on a daily basis for research, shopping, writing, reading, etc and not for a public business.

I'm aware when installing or upgrading an OS (Windows, Mac, Linux, Android) that you can install multiple languages and even use physical keyboards for multiple languages - however you can't display both languages simultaneously for taskbars, menus, files and folders, shortcuts, etc when using an OS.  Since I don't know all the meanings of words in Polish this will not help me learn in the method that works for me.

Using English and Polish as an example, you click on the taskbar in one language only and see "Start Menu" in English.  I would like to see the same words in two languages displayed next to each other, probably one on top of the other:

Start Menu
/ Menu Startowe

Open File
/ Otwórz Plik

Create New Folder
/ Stwórz Nowy Folder

etc...

Please see this question about a similar concept for English and Chinese:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/123464/2-languages-simultaneously-on-user-interface

I'm aware this would take up more visual space in the OS GUI and I use widescreen monitors when working.  I don't know why this isn't more common on computers and why we can only choose one language to use for an OS, GUI, software, etc.
I'm unfamiliar with language learning software such as Rosetta Stone, maybe there are some that have a "dual language interface" that can be toggled between multiple languages.

For software I use Google Translate and other online web-based translators to work on a rough draft in English and then edit the Polish translation as needed.  This is the only way I can write/type in Polish and a few other languages.  I can see both languages in real time as I type and edit and both can also be entered via voice and listened to via sound and this is very helpful.  If I can't modify an OS GUI then this is the next best option.
I need to research offline translator word processing programs that use downloaded language libraries.

Some internet browsers also have extensions or a built-in prompt for auto-translating a highlighted sentence or entire webpage, but you can't view both the original (and translation in a different color) unless you open up two separate tabs or windows side by side.

Are there browser extensions, scripts or other options a programmer could create for dual language display?
Here is an example of something that gets close but not quite to what I'm looking for, it's a Chrome browser extension Word Sponge:
https://thewordsponge.com ,
https://vocal.media/futurism/you-can-learn-a-language-just-with-a-browser-extension-and-no-practicing

I'm not asking about using multiple programming languages such as Python, C, etc or troubleshooting glitches and problems with multi language support on an OS or keyboard.  I mention this because it seems most of the search results I found after hours of searching are about that and not what I'm looking for.

Would it be acceptable to cross-post this question in other stacks as a link to this question with a short blurb tailored to that stack?
For example in: Software Recommendations, Software Engineering, Super User, User Experience, etc.  Thank you.

Comment: From a technical standpoint this is probably possible, but at very least it would require some software development to create a custom language pack, which, instead of translating "Start Menu" to "Menu Startowe", that instead it would translate it to your parallel text version of "Start Menu / Menu Startowe". However, there's probably little incentive for Microsoft to develop this, so you'd have to develop such a custom language pack yourself, which will involve research and software development work.

Comment: "Would it be acceptable to cross-post this" - probably not as the same question. However, if you decide to actually develop your own language pack then perhaps you could ask a new specific question about the details of how to do that on its own, and that might be an appropriate Q for either Super User (e.g. for how to extract/edit the contents of Windows language packs) or Software Engineering.

Comment: Also, from a user perspective, personally I've never found it hard to read UIs in other languages, as soon as I'm familiar with the script. Your examples of "Menu Startowe" and "Otwórz Plik" give a hint as to why -- even if you can't read it at all, you know *where* those things are. The Start Menu is generally always in the same place, and "Open File" is, as a rule, the first item in the menu. And so on. For complicated interfaces, you can approach these as a new user perspective. Learn only the translations for the functions you actually need, on a need-to-know basis.